# Application URL is not opening when i execute the automation script through jenkins

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio

Application URL is not opening when i execute the automation script through jenkins. The page is saying like "Site can't be reached" but when i execute from katalon studio it was working fine. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

This is my test URL:

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html

[image]

Comment: Can you please check proxy at your jenkins or node machine

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Not getting any error message in jenkins console

Comment: @AnkurSingh - I checked proxy in jenkins and its proper. Do you know how to configure proxy in jenkins?